# ScrollViewer is not working with grid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have this built and I add text boxes to it programmatically and update after each addition but the scrollViewer never becomes scrollable just grayed out arrows. I'm only adding textBoxes to one of the stackPanels, could that be it? If so is there some work around for that? I'd appreciate any help, I've spent much too long on this silly problem.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewerMain" VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="368" Width="410" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="150,309,150,-35.5">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="368" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="410" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelPlayerNames" Grid.Column="0" Height="368"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelWins" Grid.Column="4" Height="368"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelHours" Grid.Column="5" Height="368"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelKills" Grid.Column="1" Height="368"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelDeaths" Grid.Column="2" Height="368"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelRatio" Grid.Column="3" Height="368"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What's the ScrollViewer contained in?

Comment: Nothing. What should it be contained in?

Comment: A ScrollViewer is needed for when whatever you are displaying (in this case the Grid) could overflow the parent container. If that container is something like a StackPanel (say) which sizes to that content then the contents will never overflow and the scroll bars won't become enabled. Having said that the Grid should autoscroll so you don't need an external ScrollViewer.

Comment: So I should just delete the ScrollViewer and then it will work?

Comment: That didn't work...

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what's going on then.

Comment: Try using MaxHeight instead of Height on scrollviewer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Grid should not have a fixed height. If your Grid (inside your ScrollViewer) is ALWAYS 368 pixels tall, and that your ScrollViewer is bigger than 368 pixels tall, then there is always no overflow.